# Finding out if a string is in a dictionary

Tags: python-3.x

```
works = {'K. 162': 'Symphony No. 22 in C major',
         'K. 216': 'Violin Concerto No. 3',
         'K. 218': 'Violin Concerto No. 4',
         'K. 219': 'Violin Concerto No. 5', 
         'K. 550': 'Symphony No. 40 in G minor',
         'K. 551': 'Symphony No. 41 in C major, "Jupiter"'}
```

I am supposed to create two dictionaries, "concertos" to contain all violin concertos, and "symphonies" to contain all symphonies.

```
    concerto = {}
    symphonies = {}
    for key, value in works.items(): 
        if "Symphony" in works:
            symphonies[key]= value

print(concerto)
```

I have tried this and got no values printed in my code.

Comment: `if "Symphony" in value:`

Answer (score 1):

```
works = {'K. 162': 'Symphony No. 22 in C major',
         'K. 216': 'Violin Concerto No. 3',
         'K. 218': 'Violin Concerto No. 4',
         'K. 219': 'Violin Concerto No. 5',
         'K. 550': 'Symphony No. 40 in G minor',
         'K. 551': 'Symphony No. 41 in C major, "Jupiter"'}
concerto = {}
symphonies = {}
for key, value in works.items():
    if "Symphony" in value:
        symphonies[key]= value
    else:
        concerto[key]= value

print(concerto)
```

Try this it will work according to your expectation